# Прослушивание событий кликов

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Новичок в android studio. Нужно отслеживать события кликов и выводить в консоль. Есть метод `onTouchEvent`, но не знаю какие параметры задавать. Помогите!

Comment: события кликов куда?

Comment: В `onTouchEvent` не вы задаёте параметры, а система, она же его и вызывает. Если вам что-то не понятно - показывайте вашу попытку (код) и поясняйте внятно что у вас не получается. Приводить вам целые параграфы из учебника никто не будет - его вы сами должны прочесть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ловятся клики просто

```
img_menu_21 =  view.findViewById(R.id.img_menu_21);
// короткое нажатие
img_menu_21.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     // действие по нажатию
});
// долгое нажатие
img_menu_21.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
     // действие по нажатию
     return true;
});
```

Вывод в консоль

```
System.out.println("Текст");
```

Что касаемо onTouchEvent

```
img_menu_21.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // действие по нажатию
     } else  {
     }
     return true;
});
```